Prove that $x\sin\frac{1}{x}$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ using $\delta$-$\epsilon$
I got to this point:
$|f(x) - f(y)| \le (\lvert x\rvert\cdot\ \lvert \sin\frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y}\rvert) + (\lvert \sin\frac{1}{y}\rvert\cdot\lvert x-y|)$
So I can bound $|\sin\frac{1}{y}|$ by $1$
and bound $ \lvert \sin\frac{1}{x} - \sin\frac{1}{y}\rvert) $ by $2$
So I'm wondering how do I choose delta in terms of epsilon from
$|f(x) - f(y)| \le (2\cdot|x|) + |x-y| \lt (2 \cdot |x|) + \delta < \epsilon$
since $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$?
Do I let $|x|$ approach $0$ and just let $\delta$ = $\epsilon$?

For any given $\epsilon>0$ you can split the interval $(0,1)$ into 2 slightly overlapping subintervals $(0,\epsilon]$ and $[\frac12\epsilon, 1)$, the first of which allows you to just define $\delta=\epsilon$ which trivially satisfies $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. And to work on the second subinterval you can just make use of the first inequality in your post to find a sufficiently small $\delta$ to bound $|f(x)-f(y)|$.

Extend it  continuously to $[0,1]$. Then since $[0,1]$ is compact it is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$, therefore on $(0,1)$ .

@psl2Z Correct, but not an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument.

@PaulFrost Yeah, ok. But maybe as another idea.

What is the source of your question? Are you allowed to use that $\sin$ is uniformly continuous?

@PaulFrost No, just straight up $\delta$-$\epsilon$. Practice problem for a test. I did it with the extension theorem on $[0,1]$ before.

You got the inequality
$$\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \le \lvert x \rvert \cdot\left\lvert \sin \frac 1 x - \sin \frac 1 y \right\rvert  +  \left\lvert \sin \frac 1 y \right\rvert \cdot \lvert x - y \rvert \le \lvert x \rvert \cdot\left\lvert \sin \frac 1 x - \sin \frac 1 y \right\rvert  +   \lvert x - y \rvert. $$
This is correct, but I do not think it will help you in this form. Let us transform it once more. We have $$\sin \frac 1 x - \sin \frac 1 y = 2 \cos\left(\frac{\frac 1 x + \frac 1 y}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\frac 1 x - \frac 1 y}{2}\right) ,$$
thus
$$\left\lvert \sin \frac 1 x - \sin \frac 1 y \right\rvert \le 2\left\lvert \sin\left(\frac{y-x}{2xy}\right)\right\rvert $$
and
$$\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \le 2\lvert x \rvert \cdot \left\lvert \sin\left(\frac{y-x}{2xy}\right)\right\rvert +  \lvert x- y \rvert . \tag{1}$$
Since $x \in (0,1)$, this yields the two inequalities
$$\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \le 2\lvert x \rvert  +  \lvert x- y \rvert , \tag{2}$$
$$\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \le 2 \left\lvert \sin\left(\frac{y-x}{2xy}\right)\right\rvert +  \lvert x- y \rvert . \tag{3}$$
Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $\sin$ is continuous, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\lvert \sin z \rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ for $\lvert z \rvert < \delta$. Let $\delta' = \min(\frac{\epsilon^2\delta}{16}, \frac{\epsilon}{8})$.
Now consider $x, y$ such that $\lvert x - y \rvert < \delta'$.
Case 1. $x < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$.
Then by $(2)$
$$\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert < 2\frac{\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{8} < \epsilon .$$
Case 2. $x \ge  \frac{\epsilon}{4}$.
Then $y > \frac{\epsilon}{8}$ and $\left\lvert\frac{y-x}{2xy} \right\rvert < \frac{\delta'}{2\frac{\epsilon}{4}\frac{\epsilon}{8}} = \frac{16\delta'}{\epsilon^2} \le \delta$ and by $(3)$
$$\lvert f(x) - f(y) \rvert \le 2\frac{\epsilon}{4} + \frac{\epsilon}{8} < \epsilon .$$
